# Log in existent user when they try to register - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

If an existing user enters correct email / password combo on registration, I'm trying to *sign him in* instead of displaying an error message e.g. 'email is already in use'.

The Registration form has 4 fields:

```
Firstname
Lastname
Email
Password
```

How can i lookup if the user exists and then log him in?

Where i am stuck:

```
# Finding the user and if the entered password is valid
user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

Comment: Don't you have `SessionsController` in your app (and its action `create`)?

Comment: I'm talking about `RegistrationsController`. When a user tries to register again, but has an account already.

Comment: What's your question?.. Oh I see.

Comment: @TheMiniJohn: yeah, I got that. I meant that SessionsController (if you have one) contains code for signing user in (so that you can copy-reuse it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sign_in` method in controller.

```
if user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
  sign_in(user, :bypass => true)
  redirect root_path
else
  # do something else.
end
```